# GCP Monitoring counter metrics displays value as 1.2M

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring

I have a scorecard widget, in which i am trying to display the sum of a metric for day. I get the value as 1.2M. Is there a way that i can get to see the raw whole value like 1,200,000

For values below a million, it displays like 798,789 this. But GCP always shows values rounded up to 2 places